# How many times has inclement weather foiled attempts to navally invade the UK?

Tags: war, united-kingdom, naval

Inclusive of situations where inclement or unseasonable weather delayed the ability to set sail long enough that British ships/fleets were able to foil the plan by direct actions, how many times has this occurred in the history of the UK?

In my casual reading I've come across a few famous instances, so I'm curious to know exactly how many *less famous* times weather has forestalled invasions (or large-scale fleet battles) that would have otherwise caused some problems for England/Britain/the UK.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done.  Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I think we need some clarification on timespan and what you mean by "England/Britain/the UK". Also what constitutes an invasion, the landing of some troops or the landing of a whole army?

Comment: What "few famous instances" do you already know?

Comment: Do you want answers regarding invasions the *political* entity of the UK, or the *geographical area* of the British Isles?

Comment: The weather was iffy yesterday, so I called off my solo attempt to invade.